# using an array in two different forms C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem with arrays which are made from class; actually I can make an array from a class and in the first form I set the data in may array, but when I switch to my second form and create an object from my class, I find my array empty so I can't use the information witch I had entered into my array.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string _name;
    string _department;
    int _id;
    int _count;
    int counter = 0;
    Mediator m = new Mediator();
    Employee ee = new Employee();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Add_to_Array_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _name = txtName.Text;
        _department = txtDepartment.Text;
        _id = int.Parse(txtID.Text);
        _count = counter;
        m.Set_Value(_name, _department, _id,_count);
        counter++;
        Exchange();
        //-----------------------------------
        txtDepartment.Text = "";
        txtID.Text = "";
        txtName.Text = "";
    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(m.array[0].E_Name);
        listBox1.Items.Add(m.array[0].E_Department);
        listBox1.Items.Add(m.array[0].E_ID.ToString());
        //---------------------------------------------------
        listBox1.Items.Add(m.array[1].E_Name);
        listBox1.Items.Add(m.array[1].E_Department);
        listBox1.Items.Add(m.array[1].E_ID.ToString());
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();          
    }
```

---

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   Mediator M;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Show2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(M.array[0].E_Name);
        listBox1.Items.Add(M.array[0].E_Department);
        listBox1.Items.Add(M.array[0].E_ID.ToString());
        //---------------------------------------------------
        listBox1.Items.Add(M.array[1].E_Name);
        listBox1.Items.Add(M.array[1].E_Department);
        listBox1.Items.Add(M.array[1].E_ID.ToString());            
    }
```

---

```
class Employee
{
    string Name;
    string Department;
    int ID;

    //**************************
    public string E_Name
    {
        get { return Name; }
        set { Name = value; }
    }

    public string E_Department
    {
        get { return Department; }
        set { Department = value; }
    }

    public int E_ID
    {
        get { return ID; }
        set { ID = value; }
    }
}
```

---

```
class Mediator
{
   public Employee[] array = new Employee[5];

   public void Set_Value(string name,string department,int id,int count)
   {
       array[count] = new Employee();
       array[count].E_Name = name;
       array[count].E_Department = department;
       array[count].E_ID = id;
   }
}
```

Comment: i didnt understand well but if you want to keep your array when you create another object from that class then you can use static field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest that you don't make Mediator m static. 
IMHO this is a hack and you don't want to get in the habit of effectively making global variables everywhere, it will come back to bite you as you progress through your career.

The better solution is to pass Form2 only the data it needs to work on.
I'm guessing Form2 only needs to display the list of Employees, so you should create a Property in Form2 as follows:

```
public Employee[] Employees {get; set;}
```

[If you need more than just the list of employees then you should rather have a property for the Mediator - public Mediator Mediator {get; set;} ]

You then need to send this data to the second form just before you show it:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Employees = m.array;
f2.Show();
```

Because the data is sent by reference any changes you make in form2 will reflect in the objects stored in form1.

---

Another option is to structure your program using the MVC pattern. It's a little bit more advanced, but it's a great pattern to keep your winForms apps neat and tidy. If you are building a wizard style app then I would strongly suggest this approach.

---

As an aside note you can also clean up the code quite a bit by using a list instead of an array to store the employee data - this will also make the code more adaptable to larger numbers of employees in the future.
You can also use C#s automatic properties to reduce the amount of code you need to write. So your code can look like this this instead:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{ 
    private Mediator _mediator = new Mediator(); 

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Add_to_Array_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var newEmployee = new Employee
        {
            Name = txtName.Text,
            Department = txtDepartment.Text,
            ID = int.Parse(txtID.Text)
        };

        _mediator.Employees.Add(newEmployee);

        Exchange();
        //-----------------------------------
        txtDepartment.Text = "";
        txtID.Text = "";
        txtName.Text = "";
    }

    private void Search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var employee in _mediator.Employees)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(employee.Name);
            listBox1.Items.Add(employee.Department);
            listBox1.Items.Add(employee.ID.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Employees = _mediator.Employees;
        f2.Show();
    }
}


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Show2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var employee in Employees)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(employee.Name);
            listBox1.Items.Add(employee.Department);
            listBox1.Items.Add(employee.ID.ToString());
        } 
    }
}

class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; } 
}

class Mediator
{
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }

    public Mediator()
    {
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you because of your rich and helpful answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for your problem would be to add the `static` keyword in your array definition. this will make it stateless and therefor there won't be a new (instance of the) array being created each time you access it.
You should also consider placing this array in some kind of a static class that will be in charge of handling this kind of global variables.
As for your edits, you have at least 2 options here: the first one is making the `Mediator` class and the `array` inside `static`; or create a property in your second form like `public string [] SomeArray {get; set;}` and pass the array to it after declaring the `... = new Form2();` and before calling the `.Open()`

Comment: thank you , but I've used this method , but when ever I use from (static) , my access to that array in Form1 and Form2 would disappear , and in this case  using obj is seem to be  useless.

Comment: what do you mean disappear?

Comment: for example : public static int[ ] myarray = new int[5]  , this is fine and I can use from this array every where , but the problem is here : public string Employee[ ] myarray = new Employee[ 5] ,  first array is ok but second one does not exist when I want to use it in forms ,

Comment: You shouldn't use the `new` keyword after the array has been created. Just access it by its name

Comment: Excuse me my I ask you take look to edited question , maybe you can find solution of my problem , actually I did what you said , in Form 2 I created a object (M) without new , but It was't useful ,

Comment: Thank you , you advise was very answer that I wanted. I used from (static), and i I called the array in  this way : Mediator.array[i]                                              thanks again :)

Comment: Using global static variables like this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of Form1 in Form2 to use the array you've created.

You have two options;
First one, you can store an instance of Form1 in a common class so you can reach it from Form2.

Second option; you need to pass reference of Form1 to your Form2 instance.